# how to make new object "new" for a week

Tags: php

I'm making an e-commerce site. What I'm trying to implement is that when you add a new product, this product will have a tag `new arrival` on it. The problem is after a day this tag will be removed and I want it to last a week. Here's what I've done so far:

```
<?php
$datetoday = date("Y-m-d");                                                                     
$date = strtotime($datetoday);                                                                      
$date = strtotime("+7 day", $date);

if ($datetoday != $row["date"])                                                     
{                                                     
}
else                                                     
{
?>

  <h4> New </h4>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: so what's your question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an instance of the `\DateTime` class and compare the one you have to the one which is in the past. The objects can be compared directly with itself:

```
$aWeekAgo = new \DateTime('-1 week');

$datetoday = '2019/04/05';

if((new \DateTime($datetoday)) > $aWeekAgo)
{
    echo 'new';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Take the timestamp, add one weeks worth of seconds to it. Then check if the current timestamp is less than that number to see if its new.

```
<?php
if($row['date'] + 604800 > time()) {
    echo '<h4>New</h4>';
}
else {
    echo '<h4>Old</h4>';
}
```

---

If your $row['date'] variable is not a unix timestamp, use strtotime to convert it to a timestamp.

```
<?php
$time = strtotime($row['date']) + 604800;
if($time > time()) {
    echo '<h4>New</h4>';
}
else {
    echo '<h4>Old</h4>';
}
```

Comment: when I try your code, all of the items got an Old tags